# Is it possible to include the expandable rows in exports?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have a ui-grid that I export to pdf. The export process works great. I recently added sub rows that can be expanded. These expandable rows are not included in the export. Is there a way to include that nested information in the PDF?

Comment: Did you find the answer ?